# Rotating a basis vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let B and B' be the two different bases for vector space V.

Suppose B and B' are related by a rotation R

Show that rotation matrix Q in terms of the new basis is still orthogonal

Comment: In what basis is $R$ expressed?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a vector $x$ expressed in $B$ and $x^\prime$ expressed in $B^\prime$. These are the same vector, but in different coordinate systems.

Let $Q$ be a transformation that rotates one vector to the other, say
$$x^\prime = Q x$$
Then to rotate back, $x = Q^T x^\prime$. Then 
$$x = Q^T x^\prime = Q^T Q x$$
so $$x = Q^T Q x$$
and we must have that $$I = Q^T Q$$ (because the equation must always satisfy $x = x$) which implies that your rotation matrix $Q$ is orthogonal.

Now you must show why rotating back to the original coordinates is the transpose of the rotation matrix. Hint: think about the angles between axes between your bases $B$ and $B^\prime$.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation matrix is orthogonal matrix. The othoginal matrix in rotated coordinates is just a muliplication of some othorginal matrix, so it is still Orthoginal. $B' = R^TQR$ for some rotaion matrix R.